# AWS Cloudwatch Per-Instance CPU monitoring on ASG

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up some metrics on an AWS CloudWatch board for our Autoscaling groups which would display the current CPU usage of each individual host in the Autoscaling group.

I've tried to use AWS's built-in searches, but none of them seem to relate to what I want. The ASG searches don't turn over per-instance CPU metrics, and using EC2 instances as the search filter returns all EC2 instances in our region rather than allowing me to target just the specific ASG.

I've tried:

```
SEARCH('{AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName="CPUUtilization"', 'Average', 300)
```

But this returns all the CPU metrics from our entire fleet.

I've also tried:

```
Region
us-west-2
Namespace
AWS/EC2
Metric name
CPUUtilization
AutoScalingGroupName
production-web-WebAutoScaleGroup-B43QRLMZOCTJ
```

But this returns only the average of the CPU usage in the total ASG.

Is there no way to filter the CPU usage statistics by ASG?

Comment: Does your ASG have detailed monitoring enabled? Do you have the cw agent installed & configured to send "os specific" metrics on the ASG instances to CW? FYI you could set your ASG to add tags to the instances, then build your query with those tag(/s).

Comment: @MisterSmith I believe our ASG has detailed monitoring enabled. We have Cloudwatch agents on each machine and I believe they're configured to capture all metrics available (linux hosts).

Comment: Actually on closer inspection i dont see any CPU core specific metrics in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html - i think you might need to create a custom metric yourself (bash/aws CLI from a cronscript or whatever api language you know) if the buitlin ones dont suit your needs. This is an example dashboard using Lambda that filters by tag on the instances https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ec2-global-dashboard/blob/master/amazon-ec2-global-dashboard.yaml